# GeneXus X tutorials

Tags: genexus

I'm currently evaluating GeneXus X, and I'd like to know where I could get tutorials (either in English, Spanish, Portuguese, it doesn't matter) on the following subjects:

- Report Creation
- Database Reverse Engineering Tool
- Advanced transaction creation (relations, menu, rules, events)
- Deploying
- Interoperation with external DLL's

I'm using GeneXus X ev1, My knowledge base is in C#.

Comment: Given this is a commercial product, have you considered asking the producers?

Comment: @Lazarus Yes, I'm in contact with them, and they're really slow with not-yet-customers. That will be taken into account in our final decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marcelo, all the topics your are asking for are covered, at least in spanish, here:
http://training.genexus.com/Tutorial/tutorials?es,,MNU;E;19;2;MNU;

More under wiki.genexus.com

Answer (score 3):

You can download the GeneXus Quick Start Guide from this url, http://www.genexususa.com/portal/hgxpp001.aspx?19,61,1055,O,E,0,MNU;E;225;3;MNU;,

Answer (score 1):

You can direct yourself to gxtechnical.com

Gabriel.

Answer (score 1):

Marcelo, specifically about the Database reverse engineering process with Genexus, here you can find an overview: http://wiki.gxtechnical.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?2414